# In Word VBA, display the selection in Word while MsgBox asks me what to do

Tags: vba, ms-word

I copied code from the web to cycle through all the text boxes in a document. For each text box, I'd like to highlight it (like it would be if I were using the Word "find") then pop up a message box asking if I'd like to delete it or keep it.

I think I have everything working properly except the code that is supposed to update the display so I can see the selected text box that MsgBox is asking me about. This is the current code. Application.ScreenRefresh doesn't do the trick. What should I put in its place so I can see the currently selected text box at the time of the MsgBox call?

```
    Sub AskAboutTextBoxes()
        Dim objShape As Shape
        Dim iAnswer As Integer
        Dim i as Integer
        ScreenUpdating = True

        For i = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
            If ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).Type = msoTextBox Then
                ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).Select
                Application.ScreenRefresh
                iAnswer = MsgBox("Delete this box?", vbYesNoCancel, "Located Text Box")
                If iAnswer = vbYes Then
                    ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).Delete
                ElseIf iAnswer = vbCancel Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: Record a macro to get the syntax for applying and removing text highlight. You can ignore the recorded lines that start with `Options`. Then look up the help text for the [`TextRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.textframe.textrange) object to see how to get to the text in the text box.

Comment: Using immediate mode, I know that `ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).Select` properly selects the box and puts handles around it. That is sufficient highlighting. The problem is that it occurs off-screen. The document doesn't scroll to put the selection in the displayed portion of the document.

Comment: Writing the above response led me to a different way to think about the problem. That change resulted in the solution I was looking for. I posted it as the answer. Thank you for your suggestion; it was the catalyst.

Answer (score 0):

The way to update what is displayed is to use `ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView Selection, True` rather than `Application.ScreenRefresh`. Making that replacement got it working properly.